# Is there a module that makes Taxonomy tags like they are on stackexchange sites?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm Looking for a module that makes my free tagging taxonomy tags like they are on this or any other stack exchange site. I would like for when a user puts their cursor in the Autocomplete tag field, it displays a list of suggested tags for them to select. Also, I would like to incorporate tag aliases/synonyms so multiple tags relate to one another. I'm running Drupal 7 and I figure I could use permissions on my taxonomy set to allow people to create new tags based on their role. Does anyone know of a module or way to get this functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Active tags](http://drupal.org/project/active_tags) will give you the look & feel of stackexchange's tags but won't provide the nice description and suggestion list that SE sites have.

[image: Drupal active tags module]

Comment: Thank you, now I just need to figure out a way to get the suggestion list.